# Cannot add Cordova-plugin-file to Meteor WhatsApp tutorial project

Tags: cordova, meteor

I want to modify the Meteor WhatsApp tutorial project to access a local file on an IOS device. I believe I need to use the Cordova plugin Cordova-plugin-file. However, I cannot seem to find a way to install it.
I have tried several CLI commands, with the following results:

meteor cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
ionic: command not found

meteor add cordova-plugin-file
=> Errors while parsing arguments:
While adding package cordova-plugin-file:
error: no such package

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just found the correct command format as: meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1

Comment: Please close your question, or answer it and mark as closed if you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the correct command format as: meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1